# AngularJs filter and scope inside http directive

Tags: angularjs, http, filter, return

How can i return one data with this controller with filter function and http inside of it.

i also use routeparams just for data comparison only.

```
.controller("projectSelectedController", 
    ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams',
        function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
            //Link to compare
            console.log($routeParams.selectedProject);

            $http
            .get("../Models/projectListRecords.php")
            .then(function(projectGet) {
                //Return all data
                console.log(projectGet);

                //Pass to Scope one Data than === Link
                $scope.projectSelected = projectGet.data.projectListRecords.filter(function(projectSelectedFilter) {                        
                    // return projectSelectedFilter.projectListName === $routeParams.selectedProject;
                    console.log(projectSelectedFilter.projectListName === $routeParams.selectedProject);
                })[0];


            });

        }
    ]);
```

and in my view is

```
{{projectSelected.myProjectName}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'filter' property looks odd.  It looks like you are using a filter predicate that is assumed to exist on the returned results 'projectGet' they won't.  This is just a JSON object.  You need to use a separate filter function to return the results.  LoDash is probably a good candidate.  Your filter code should look something like this:

```
var filteredResults = _.filter(projectGet.data.projectListRecords, function(record) {
    return record.projectListName === $routeParams.selectedProject;
});
if (filteredResults.length > 0) {
    $scope.projectSelected = filteredResults[0];
}
```

Comment: yup it's json object. with my filter it return like true if === and false if not the from that i want to pull the only true value :(  what is "_." in your code?

Comment: The lodash library - strongly recommended.

Comment: thanks! :) ill come back to upvote one i get 15+ rep :)